# How to define an explicit casting operator in swift?

Tags: swift, casting

**Background**

I have a class that want to hide the implementation details.

```
class Foo
{
  var i : Int
}

let f = Foo()
```

*Is there a way to define an explicit cast operator so that gets invoked on `f as Int`?*

If not, is there a canonical method name that I should use like `asInt() -> Int`?

Comment: You cannot use `as` that way for _any_ type. You can't say `4 as Double` so why on earth do you think it would be possible for your object? That is not what `as` means in Swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know this is what you want but, you can implement cast like `Int` initializer:

```
extension Int {
    init(_ foo:Foo) {
        self = foo.i
    }
}

let f = Foo()
f.i = 12
let intVal = Int(f) // -> 12
```

Comment: this seems to be closest to what I am looking for - ty